# Dotnet pack compatibility check fails when upgrading .net 6 to .net 8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

I have this interface `Interface`

```
public interface Interface
{
   public string SomeName { get; set;}
   
   [NotRequired]
   public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

This library was on .NET 6 and I'm upgrading it to .NET 8. And when I do the `dotnet pack` to make sure that the nuget package is still backward compatible, there's this error:

> /Users/joe/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.ApiCompat.ValidatePackage.targets(39,5): error : API compatibility errors between 'lib/net6.0/Some.Interface.dll' (/Users/joe/.nuget/packages/some.interface/2.3.11/some.interface.2.3.11.nupkg) and 'lib/net6.0/Some.Interface.dll'
>
> Member 'System.DateTime Some.Interface.SomeDate.get' exists on [Baseline] lib/net6.0/Some.Interface.dll but not on lib/net6.0/Some.Interfaces.dll

So from what I understand, somehow the getter of `SomeDate` properties is not visible anymore, but it's still there, no changes have been made to the definition of the interface and its properties.

Any idea on what's going on here?

UPDATE:
I have a further look into the change history of this piece of code and see that this

```
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

was changed from

```
public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
```

But this change happened like 6 months ago, and our build pipeline (using net 6 and then 7) haven't had any fail since then.
It's just now when I upgraded the project to .net 8 and run this locally with .net 8, the check fails.

Comment: Not sure this is the case, but I've seen the tool generate incorrect messages as well. So it might really be a false error as well.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? One possibility would be that trimming is affecting things somehow but I would expect it to work.

Comment: So I looked into the history of the code and see that the changing some type to nullable somehow got away with .net6 and 7 sdk, but with dotnet 8 doesn't like it.